# Deployment woes: What do I do after "svn up"?

Tags: django, svn, deployment, tortoisesvn

I've got several questions. I have no idea how the heck to deploy...

After doing "svn up" on my production server, I'm not sure how to "refresh" my server so that the changes are reflected when you visit it. What can I do to refresh my server to see the changes in production? (I tried rebooting.)

I also noticed that some of the files that I changed weren't truly updated. I deleted a file and saw that doing "svn up" would bring the file back. I went back and deleted everything in the web app's folders, including the svn files (probably a mistake). (I should be safe since I have the prod revisions on the test server, I assume...) So, how can I bring these files back?

I need all the advice and resources on this that I can get. Feel free to post anything else that will get me through this process.

Comment: When you 'deleted a file', did you actually tell subversion you deleted it, or did you just delete it in your working directory? You might need to actually use `svn delete` to remove it from the repository as well.

Comment: I only deleted in my working directory. I don't have any need for "svn delete" here.

Comment: *"I also noticed that some of the files that I changed weren't truly updated. I deleted a file and saw that doing "svn up" would bring the file back."* If you don't want `svn up` to bring a file back, then you need to `svn delete` it.

Comment: I don't think we understand each other.  On my desktop, the working copy I checked out is correct. When I committed this to prod and did "svn up",  my changes weren't on the production server. 

So, I just deleted everything to see what would happen if I did "svn up" again. My goal was to get the working copy that I checked in.

Comment: what Amber is trying to tell you is that the file that you think you deleted, which you think SVN resurrected, was never actually deleted in the first place. When you want to delete a file permanently, you need to perform an SVN delete, otherwise it will keep coming back. This is all based on your sentence... "I deleted a file and saw that doing "svn up" would bring the file back".

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you run your django up. If you're serving with [mod_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/)/[modwsgi](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), a simple apache restart does the trick.

If you're datamodel changed, you may need to call [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) command `migrate`.

On most Linux-Systems this can be done with `service apache2 restart`

You can do the `svn up`, `manage.py migrate` and `service apache2 restart` with [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.1/)

Fabric helps you to automate to execute shell commands over ssh.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying on mod_wsgi you can simply touch the .wsgi file and it will reload the app without having to restart your whole server/httpd/etc

Comment: Only true for mod_wsgi daemon mode.